# Programatically change focus for TextBox in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I have a class derived from TextBox in C#. I override OnClick method to show a file open dialog. Is it possible to lose focus after that? I don't want the user to be able to edit the text because at a moment the file name might be invalid. I tried to set ReadOnly = true, but one can change the text after selecting the file.

EDIT:

I added the relevant code for this. As it is now the focus will be set to next control from my Form.

```
class Property : TextBox
class FileSelectTextBox : Property
{
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
        Enabled = false;
        if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Text = dialog.FileName;
        }
        Enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET? WinForms? whot?

Comment: Can you not just set the enabled property to false?

Comment: @Felics ye so how about JMK's comment?

Comment: @JMK I don't want to disable the edit box - I need the OnClick event

Comment: @Felics so disable the control _inside_ the OnClick method. you can later `Enable` it once the user finishes with the `FileDialog`

Comment: @Shai - this works, but selects next control from my form. I don't want this - it also may be of the same type and I don't want to be able to edit it directly.

Comment: @Felics can you please post us your code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several options here:

1. Make the textbox `ReadOnly`. The textbox will still fire `OnClick` events but the text won't be editable by the user.
2. Disable the textbox at the end of your click event -- the disadvantage is that the click event won't fire a second time (which means the user won't be able to change their mind and pick a new file).
3. Simply set the focus somewhere else at the end of the click event. (`someOtherTextBox.Focus()`)

<s>**Edit:** Once last suggestion: you may want your file popup to happen in `FocusGained` rather than `OnClick`, that way the dialog will still pop up if the user tabs into the control. Of course it's your decision if that behavior is desired or not.</s>

**Edit 2:** Ignore that last edit. It's a bad suggestion that I didn't think through. (Thanks for the heads up commenter)

Comment: 1. Works fine, but it must be set AFTER showing the dialog. I tried to set it in constructor but it didn't worked. Weird...

Comment: `FocusGained` will cause event to be fired repeatedly when dialog closed..to avoid this you will have to change the focus to some other textbox or so, which is not the proper way(because that textbox may have some other work for `FocusGained` event)..

Answer (score 0):

set the `ReadOnly = true` property of the textbox (don't change it at any point of time) and it should work lonely..

and rest of the code goes like this..

```
    protected override void OnClick(EventArgs e)
        OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();

        //user can still change/edit some non-existing file/path and click OK, so set the followings
        dialog.CheckFileExists = true;
        dialog.CheckPathExists = true;

        if (dialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Text= dialog.FileName;
        }
    }
```